# How to use GridSearchCV to tune hyperparamters for RNN`s?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, keras

How to use GridSearchCV to tune hyperparamters for RNN`s?
The main issue is that .fit from scikit can only take in a 2d array but the data passed into my recurrent neural network has an extra parameter of time, which is 3d. Is there a way to still use GridSearchCV to get around this? I am only interested in tuning the number of neurons, Learning rate and epochs.

The shape of the my training data has shape `(1200, 24, 1)`, but the .fit method from scikit can only handle training data with shape `(X,Y)`.

Comment: Please explain more about the data.. About the 3 dimensions. GridSearchCV will apply cross-validation to split the data into train and test. On what dimension should the split occur?

Comment: @VivekKumar It's the shape of the data that gets passed to the fit method, not how the split or partition of the data is done. Just added this to the question.

Comment: @VivekKumar But my RNN model uses this last dimension, cause I also have data where the shape is (1200, 24, 12), where do you suggest I do the reshaping? I tried reshaping within the GridSearchCV step but it didn`t seem to work, do you know a way around this?

Comment: This is what I was asking about the shape. Please explain clearly what are the uses of each dimension of your shape, only then we can decide what to do and where to do and how to do

Comment: @VivekKumar I never mentioned anything about split, you are misunderstanding my question. For RNN`s  the shape of your data must be `(X,Y,Z)`, where `X `represents the number of samples, `Y`represents the time step and `Z`represents the number of features per time step. Read this https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/.

Comment: I am not understanding it wrong. You see GridSearchCV will split the data and needs 2-d data. For that you can reshape the data to combine 2nd and 3rd dimension. You then said that the third dimension can have different values? If the third dimension is the features as given on the page you linked, how will they vary, and why.

Comment: You can then reshape it back to correct shape when sending the model to RNN, train them, calculate scores and pass the scores back to GridSearchCV

Comment: @VivekKumar I see. You said reshape it back to correct shape when sending the model to RNN, I am not sure exactly at which point this is at. Could you show an example?

Comment: You show the code how you are doing it currently without the grid-search and I will modify it to use GridSearchCV

Comment: @VivekKumar Actually I don't think this can be solved with GridSearchCV, see here https://machinelearningmastery.com/grid-search-hyperparameters-deep-learning-models-python-keras/. Control Find 'Josep' and separately control Find 'time series'.

Comment: Well, as you wish. But if you had provided your current code, we would have implemented the GridSearchCV and even in worst case, we could have used some parts of it, so that we dont have to do it from scratch.

Comment: @VivekKumar I have the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55774632/gridsearchcv-randomizedsearchcv-with-lstm. I wonder if you have any feedback or maybe, you can clarify what do you mean by reshaping it back?