# Using GridSearchCV to Fine-tune LSTM but with reshape problem

Tags: python, numpy, keras, lstm, gridsearchcv

I'm using GridSearchCV to fine-tune the LSTM model. Because GridSearchCV input step requires 2D data but the LSTM model requires 3D data. So I have to build a Transform class to reshape 2D data to 3D before the pipeline starts running LSTM.

I get idea from this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55774632/gridsearchcv-randomizedsearchcv-with-lstm). And I'm trying to implement the method II.

However, after I managed to implement custom Transform Class. I still got a bug. Because GridSearchCv will process on cross-validation with the default setting 5. The data(total 96 rows with 153 columns) is cut as 16 * 1, 16 * 2, 16 * 3... 16 * 6 for rows. I take 4 as decomposition factor. To reshape to 3D I use statement `X.reshape(X.shape[0]/4, 4, shape[1])`

And here is my codes:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
class Shape_halfway_Transformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    y=0
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.y=y
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        X_shape=int(X.shape[0]/4)
        X=X.values.reshape(X_shape,4,X.shape[1])
        if self.y is not None:
            y_shape=int(self.y.shape[0]/4)
            y=self.y.values.reshape(y_shape, 4, self.y.shape[1])
            return X, y
        return X
```

The problem is after you convert X_train, X_test to idea shape, in later step GridSearchCV will process on a "validation X, y". In this step, from my observation it seems would check the X, y shape with a 2D shape. Bug happened at there when it uses numpy to compulsory switch 3D data to 2D. Here is part of bug reporting:

```
File "[path]\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 618, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(

File "[path]\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 1106, in check_X_y
    X = check_array(

File "[path]\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 879, in check_array
    array = _asarray_with_order(array, order=order, dtype=dtype, xp=xp)

File "[path]\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_array_api.py", line 185, in _asarray_with_order
    array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,4,153) into shape (4,4)
```

How can I solve this? I also tried to use Keras Reshape Layer but it requires a fixed shape. Cross_validation makes input length increase by a multiple with each increase. So it cant be fixed. I think I may made some mistakes on my LSTM model. I put it here:

```
def LSTM_Calling(unit_LSTM, dropout, lr, opt) -> Any:
    model = Sequential()
    #--------------how to reshape-----------------------
    # model.add(Reshape((-1, 4, 153), input_shape=(-1, 153)))
    #-------------------------------------------------------

    model.add(LSTM(units=160, activation="tanh", recurrent_activation="sigmoid", input_dim=153,
                   dropout=dropout, input_shape=(4, 153), return_sequences=False,
                   kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=42),
                   bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=42)
                   )) # return_sequences=True,
    model.add(Dense(jack.units_d, activation="sigmoid"))

    opt_sgd = "sgd" 
    opt_adam = "adam"  #Adam(learning_rate=self.learning_rate)
    opt = opt_sgd if opt==-1 else opt_adam
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=opt,  # keras.losses.kullback_leibler_divergence
                  metrics=["mse", "accuracy"])  # tf.keras.metrics.categorical_crossentropy

    # early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=jack.patience, mode="min")

    return model
```

Really appreciate if you can help me solve these problems. I'm also not sure about how the "input_shape" parameter in LSTM worked and related with input dataset shape.