# LSTM Model Input Conflict With Mainstream Encapsulate or Fine-tune Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

So recently, I was studying on LSTM model to fit stock price. However, when I trying to use GridSearchCV or KerasRegressor to fine-tune it or encapsulate it with other models such as SMOTE, it seems due to LSTM requires a 3D input (length, timestamp, dimension) which seems not compatible with the two wrapper model. Both GridSearchCV and KerasRegressor more prefer 2D input. So I wanna ask is there no way to solve this?

Although currently I realized LSTM is not that eager to have a fine-tuned model because most of time it could get a good result by long iterations, I still wanna figure out is it possible to let LSTM fit on GridSearchCV. I tried many methods but didn’t get results. I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55774632/gridsearchcv-randomizedsearchcv-with-lstm) very useful and I did as it said but got more problems. I also post [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76459036/using-gridsearchcv-to-fine-tune-lstm-but-with-reshape-problem).

Now as far as I know, it seems GridSearchCV needs our “model” class to have a function named “set_params()” to re-input new parameters for evaluation, so we have to use KerasRegressor to wrap up Keras.Sequential model. Then maybe you can put model together with other ML models into Pipeline and throw into GridSearchCV for fine-tuning.

But now if I want to use KerasRegressor to encapsulate LSTM together there also many bugs happen. The bug is also caused by different input shapes. I will put my code and bug below. So is LSTM really severely in conflict with the usually used encapsulate model? How could I overcome this question?

```
# input X_train shape (16,6,153),y_train shape(16,6,1)
model = Sequential()
# model.add(Reshape((-1, 4, 153), input_shape=(-1, 153)))
model.add(LSTM(units=unit_LSTM, input_dim=153, activation="tanh", recurrent_activation="sigmoid",
              dropout=dropout, input_shape=(6,153), return_sequences=True,
              kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=42),
              bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=42)
              ))
model.add(Dense(jack.units_d, activation="sigmoid"))

initial_prarm: dict[str: Any]=dict(dropout=0.19, opt=None, unit_LSTM=149)
wrapper_model=KerasRegressor(model=LSTM_Calling, **initial_prarm, verbose=0, shuffle=False)

wrapper_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Get bug shows:

```
Cell In[56], line 1
----> 1 wrapper_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

File lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py:762, in BaseWrapper.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, **kwargs)
    757 kwargs["epochs"] = kwargs.get(
    758     "epochs", getattr(self, "fit__epochs", self.epochs)
    759 )
    760 kwargs["initial_epoch"] = kwargs.get("initial_epoch", 0)
--> 762 self._fit(
    763     X=X,
    764     y=y,
    765     sample_weight=sample_weight,
    766     warm_start=self.warm_start,
    767     **kwargs,
    768 )
    770 return self

File lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py:918, in BaseWrapper._fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, warm_start, epochs, initial_epoch, **kwargs)
    916 # Data checks
    917 if not ((self.warm_start or warm_start) and self.initialized_):
--> 918     X, y = self._initialize(X, y)
    919 else:
    920     X, y = self._validate_data(X, y)
...
    924         estimator_name=estimator_name,
    925         allow_nan=force_all_finite == "allow-nan",
    926     )

ValueError: Found array with dim 3. None expected <= 2.
```